# Is there a way to use try. except to limit a list to numbers only so if anything else other then numbers is used such as special char or char it loops

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
var=input("Enter a list of Number to Find its Minimum, Maximum, Average and Total:")
                    try:
                            a=eval(var)
                            b=min(a)
                            c=max(a)
                            d=sum(a)/len(a)
                            e=sum(a)
                            print('min -',b,'max -',c,'avg -',d,'total -',e)
                            break
                    except NameError:
                        txt=var.isalpha()
                        if (txt==True):
                            print("Please enter a valid input")
                        else:
                            print("Please enter a valid input")
```

Errors :

```
Enter a list of Number to Find its Minimum, Maximum, Average and Total:[1,2,3ab,4]
  File "<string>", line 1
    [1,2,3ab,4]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
Enter a list of Number to Find its Minimum, Maximum, Average and Total:[@,+,_]
  File "<string>", line 1
    [@,+,_]
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Was Expecting it to print an error message like " Please enter a valid input " and ask me to type the list again.

Comment: why were you expecting that? `[1,2,3ab,4]` raises a `SyntaxError` when you `eval` it, and you arent' catching a `SyntaxError`, but this is probably not the best approach to begin with

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Don't, even if only because the user of your program shouldn't be forced to know Python list syntax. Let them enter a simple space-separated string, use `a = [int(v) for v in var.split()]`, then proceed with a list of `int` values or handle the `ValueError` raised by any call to `int`.

Comment: Why did you put `except NameError` anyway? I don't see anywhere a `NameError` is likely. I'm voting to close the question because this seems to be a basic mistake (`NameError` instead of `SyntaxError`), but correct me if I'm wrong, and please make a [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Also BTW, there are other problems with your code, like for example, why bother checking `if txt == True` (which itself is redundant) if you're just going to do the same thing either way?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few quirks that you may want to tweak:

- There is a `break` statement inside the `try`, but no `for` loop.
- Both `if` and `else` print the same text. You can't know which one printed the output.

Just by changing the captured exception type from `NameError` to `SyntaxError` should be enough:

```py
var = input("Enter a list of Number to Find its Minimum, Maximum, Average and Total:")
try:
    a = eval(var)
    b = min(a)
    c = max(a)
    d = sum(a)/len(a)
    e = sum(a)
    print('min -', b, 'max -', c, 'avg -', d, 'total -', e)
except SyntaxError:
    print("Please enter a valid input")
```

Nonetheless, if you want to print different messages for `[1,2,3ab,4]` and `[@,+,_]` you should know that `str.isalpha()` only returns `True` if **all** characters are letters, which is not true just by adding commas or brackets. I would suggest using regular expressions (regex):

```py
import re

var = input("Enter a list of Number to Find its Minimum, Maximum, Average and Total:")
try:
    a = eval(var)
    b = min(a)
    c = max(a)
    d = sum(a)/len(a)
    e = sum(a)
    print('min -', b, 'max -', c, 'avg -', d, 'total -', e)
except SyntaxError:
    if re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]', var):
        print("Text contains letters. Please enter a valid input")
    elif re.match(r'[\@\+\_]', var):
        print("Text contains special characters. Please enter a valid input")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid input")
```

You can play with regex on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com).

If you would rather not use the `re` library, you can do it iterating over the string:

```py
var = input("Enter a list of Number to Find its Minimum, Maximum, Average and Total:")
try:
    a = eval(var)
    b = min(a)
    c = max(a)
    d = sum(a)/len(a)
    e = sum(a)
    print('min -', b, 'max -', c, 'avg -', d, 'total -', e)
except SyntaxError:
    for l in var:
        if l.isnumeric() or l in [',', '[', ']']:
            continue
        if l.isalpha():
            print("Text contains letters. Please enter a valid input")
        elif l in ['@', '+', '_']:
            print("Text contains special characters. Please enter a valid input")
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input")
        break
```